# How to point django to put a template in the front page

Tags: python, django

I am trying to learn  python in the django framework, I took a course, but it was based on an earlier version of django while I am using Django 2.1.3 and python 3.7.0, so I've got errors.My question is how can I point urls.py to take an html template and put it in the main page in this version of Django?
Thank you!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Have you tried searching this up online before posting your question here? Also, please post the errors that you have received in your question.

Comment: It's not clear how you think the Django version is significant here. If you have errors, you should post them.

Comment: When you move to a new version, you should read the official documentation that comes with this version. [Here's the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/) for Django v 2.1, where' you'll also find a link to how to route urls in this version. As a new user on SO, read [Ask] first so you learn how to ask questions that are specific enough and well formulated and also to learn what kind of (home)work is expected before you ask.

Answer (score 0):

You should point urls.py to views.py for your home page.

So your urlpatterns would look like, your main app:

```
urlpatterns = [
path(r'', include('page.urls'))
]
```

urls.py in page app:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url('^$', views.page, name = 'index')]
```

And views.py like:

```
def page(request): 
    return render(request,"page.html")
```

There is tons of tutorials online. Have a look on Django documentation or YouTube . I also have blog with some info (I started learning recently too) https://adamw.eu

Answer (score 0):

I assume *Front page* stands for *Home page* and that your site is called *website*. Then in `urls.py` of `website/website` (the directory that also contains the `settings.py` file), create a `HomePage` view

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
class HomePage(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'
```

Then in `urls.py`in the same folder, do something like:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.HomePage.as_view(), name="home"),
    ]
```

You then need a `templates` folder at the root of your website, that is in `website/templates` and create `website/templates/index.html` which will be your homepage template.

In the `website/website/settings.py` file, make sure to set `TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')` and modify the `TEMPLATES` variable:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIR],
        ...  # rest of the code here
```

Reboot server, this should work fine.